# Linking cython code against libiomp5 instead of libgomp

Tags: openmp, cython, intel-mkl, libgomp

Is it possible to link `cython` code which uses OMP (say things like "prange" statements) against `libiomp5` instead of `libgomp` using `gcc`? I am aware of several posts, e.g., like [Telling GCC to *not* link libgomp so it links libiomp5 instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986091/telling-gcc-to-not-link-libgomp-so-it-links-libiomp5-instead), and others, describing how one might achieve this. However, they do not seem to work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Specifically, say I am using a most recent Anaconda distribution and have some `file.pyx` on which I do `cython -a file.pyx` to get `file.c`. Then for `libgomp` I would do things like

```
gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O3 -ffast-math -fno-strict-aliasing -march=native -fopenmp -o file.so -I/include_dirs file.c
```

Which gives me a `file.so` that shows

```
>ldd file.so
...
libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007fc3725ab000)
...
```

For `libiomp5`, and from reading the previously mentioned posts, I was *hoping* that this would do the job

```
gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O3 -ffast-math -fno-strict-aliasing -march=native -o file.so -I/include_dirs file.c -L/lib_dirs -liomp5
```

Indeed, the `file.so` I get shows

```
>ldd *.so
...
libiomp5.so => /lib_dirs/libiomp5.so (0x00007ff92c717000)
...
```

However, when I link `file.so` to some code which is forced to use a specific number of OMP threads, *only* the version of `file.so` which has been linked against `libgomp` shows more than a single thread being used. I.e. there seems to be no error from linking to `libiomp5`, but the system behaves as if no OMP pragmas would have been used in the first place.

PS.: I have also tried an additional `-Wl,--as-needed` to the `gcc` options (dunnowhatfor), but that does not change the picture.

**UPDATE: ----------------**

Following the request of user vidyalatha-intel, the following provides an example. It is not coded for optimal style, nor solves any particular problem. It is just meant to allow to reproduce the issue.

A) Some python code to invoke a `*.so` lib

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rnd

import stackovfl_OMP as sc  # THE lib

N = 600
# init a couple of 1d and 2d arrays
f = rnd.random(N)
e = rnd.random(N)
v = rnd.random((N,N))+1j*rnd.random((N,N))
z = np.linspace(0,3,150) + .05*1j
numthread = 4                      # explicitly force 4 threads
s = []

for i in z: # for each z do stuff needing OMP in sc.sit
    print(np.real(i))
    s.append([np.real(i),sc.sit(i,v,e,f,numthread)])
```

B) The cython code `stackovfl_OMP.pyx` for the lib `stackovfl_OMP.so`, doing some (rather senseless) stuff, including three loops, the outer one of which uses OMP

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# cython: language_level=3

cimport cython
cimport openmp
from cython.parallel import prange
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef np.complex128_t sit(
    np.complex128_t z,
    np.ndarray[np.complex128_t,ndim=2] t,
    np.ndarray[np.float64_t,ndim=1]    e,
    np.ndarray[np.float64_t,ndim=1]    f,
    np.int32_t nt                      # num threads
    ):
    cdef int a,b,c,l,it
    l = len(e)
    ''' si  :   Partial storage for each thread in the pool
        siv :   Nogil memviews for numpy array r/w access '''
    cdef np.ndarray[np.complex128_t,ndim=1] si = np.zeros(nt,dtype=np.complex128)
    cdef complex[:] siv = si
    
    for a in prange(l, nogil=True, num_threads=nt):     # OMP parallelization outer loop
        it = openmp.omp_get_thread_num()                # fixed within one thread
        for b in range(l):
            for c in range(l):                          # Do 'something'
                siv[it] = siv[it] + t[c,b]*t[b,a]*t[a,c]/(2*z-e[a]+e[c])*(                    
                    (f[a]-f[b])/(z-e[a]+e[b]) + (f[c]-f[b])/(z-e[b]+e[c]))
                
    return np.sum(si)                                   # return collected pool
```

With A) an B) you can go ahead as described in the original post and generate `stackovfl_OMP.so`, either linking against `libgomp` or `libiomp5`. As stated there, *only* for `libgomp` the machine ends up with four threads running, when you call `python stackovfl.py`, while the `libiomp5` linked version of `stackovfl_OMP.so` remains with  single thread only. (Additionally exporting OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 into the environment does not change this.)

Comment: Did you try exporting the OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable explicitly? If possible please provide us with a minimal reproducer so that I will try it from my end.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to the following 
link https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/optimization-and-programming/openmp-support/openmp-library-support/use-the-openmp-libraries.html

Comment: Regarding the env var OMP_NUM_THREADS, I did try both, exporting it and not exporting it, which did not change the story. Regarding the minimal version, I'll be back.

Comment: You prefer a minimal example posted here or elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, you can post it here, or else I would like to encourage you to post your issue on Intel communities(https://community.intel.com/t5/Software-Development-Tools/ct-p/software-dev-tools) as well.. we would be happy to assist you

Comment: Updated the post for code to reproduce the issue. Hope that helps.

Comment: Could you please let me know how did you check if it is running on a single thread or on 4 threads? Do i need to include something to know that thread count?

Comment: You can either (i) run `top` in any terminal app you use. You will see a column `%CPU`. For `python stackovfl.py` from the example you will then see a certain percentage dedicated to that process. In my case the `libgomp` version shows 400%, the `libiomp5` shows 100%. ... you may not believe, that this tells you that the  `libgomp` version uses 4 threads while the `libiomp5` uses only a single ... therefore, you can also do (ii) `top -H`, which will split the process info into actual threads. In my case `top -H` show 4 threads for `libgomp` and 1 for `libiomp5` (see also `man top`)

Comment: yeah, gcc + libiomp combination seems to run on a single thread. So i tried using the intel compiler (icx compiler, you can get it by downloading oneAPI toolkits (recommended Base & HPC) with the following command and now i could see it runs on multiple threads) command used >> icx -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O3 -ffast-math -fno-strict-aliasing -march=native -qopenmp -o stackovfl_OMP.so -I/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/python3.9/envs/2023.0.0/include/python3.9 stackovfl_OMP.c  .. Please try it if possible and let me know

Comment: The original question was, if it "... possible to link `cython` code which uses OMP (say things like "prange" statements) against `libiomp5` instead of `libgomp` using `gcc` ...". Suggesting to replace the GNU toolchain with the Intel one is not really related to that. Thanks anyway for confirming my test case.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been mentioned by me at the Google cython-users group at https://groups.google.com/g/cython-users/c/2niCShTH4OE where the answer was finally given by cython core-developer D. Woods.

In a nutshell: Split the compile and link step. In the compile step you can then emit the OMP pragmas. The resulting `*.o` object file can indeed be linked directly to `libiomp5`. In the example I gave this boils down to, e.g.:

```
gcc -c -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O3 -ffast-math -fno-strict-aliasing -march=native -fopenmp stackovfl_OMP.c -o stackovfl_OMP.o -I/include_paths

gcc -shared -pthread -Wl,--as-needed stackovfl_OMP.o -o stackovfl_OMP.so -L/library_paths -liomp5

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/library_paths
```

Finally, `ldd` shows `stackovfl_OMP.so` to be linked against `libiomp5` and it runs as many threads as one likes. (...do I get any performance difference w.r.t.  `libgomp` ... nope.)

Thx. D. Woods. Credit to those who deserve it.

Comment: Yes, since -fopenmp option is missing in the compilation the OpenMP codegen is not activated and hence it is running on single thread. You can directly add the -fopenmp option to the command >>gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O3 -ffast-math -fno-strict-aliasing -march=native -o file.so -I/include_dirs file.c -L/lib_dirs -liomp5
I tested it and it worked.